# Force Git to fail when password required, instead of prompting for password

Tags: git

I am working on an application where a user can enter a Git repository, which is then cloned to the local machine. In some cases (such as a mistyped URL pointing to a nonexistent repo on Github), the Git client will prompt the user for a username and password. I do not want this behavior -- I just want Git to fail with a non-zero error status. A non-interactive error message is OK, I just to avoid the password prompt causing my application to hang.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the [`GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` environment variable](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTERMINALPROMPTcode) to `0` if you don't want git to prompt for any input.

```
>>> git clone https://github.com/private/private.git 
Cloning into 'private'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
>>> GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0 git clone https://github.com/private/private.git
Cloning into 'private'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Alternatively, can set the [`GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITASKPASScode) or [`core.askpass` configuration value](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreaskPass) to `true` (or a blank script).

```
>>> git clone https://github.com/private/private.git 
Cloning into 'private'...
Username for 'https://github.com':
>>> GIT_ASKPASS=true git clone https://github.com/private/private.git
Cloning into 'private'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/private/private.git/'
```

Both solutions have non-zero exit codes.

Comment: false(1) typically serves the purpose of "do nothing, and fail at it". No need for an empty script.

Comment: Interesting. Is there some cross-platform alternative if no such `true` binary is available? Or would I have to ship such a program along w/ my script?

Comment: @shadowtalker: I believe true(1) and false(1) are mandated by POSIX, so they're already very cross-platform. Or at least as portable as expecting a shell that'll execute an empty script :)

Comment: @shadowtalker I just noticed the [`GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` environment variable](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTERMINALPROMPTcode) which might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: I could not get this to work at all. I'm cloning via **SSH** and it still asks for a password! I tried various values for `core.askPass`, `credential.helper`, `GIT_ASKPASS`, `SSH_ASKPASS`, `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT` without any effect. The [only thing](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand) I found that helped was `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=no"`

Comment: GIT_ASKPASS=false not working for me

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT=0`, the following helps to also suppress credential manager windows

`git -c credential.helper= <rest of commands>`